# How to customize an html dropdown menu using <div><span>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a pricing table to showcase service pricing based on terms of purchase (Monthly, Annually, Trieannually).

Choosing an option from the dropdown changes the link attribute using javascript which is exactly what I want, however, the actual styling on the dropdown options seems to be rather difficult.

Trying to achieve this for hours on end without any working solution.

Attached is an image of what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
    <div class="ive-hpbox">
<h3>Simple Price Box</h3>

<div class="dropdown-plans">
<select id="dynamic_select">
  <option value="cart.php?a=add&pid=1548&billingcycle=monthly">
    <h3>Monthly</h3>
    <span class="hp-price">$12.00/mo</span>
  </option>
  <option value="cart.php?a=add&pid=1548&billingcycle=annually" selected>
    <h3>SAVE 50%</h3>
    <span class="hp-disc-price">1 Year at <strike>$144.00/mo</strike></span>
    <span class="hp-price">$72.00/mo</span>
  </option>
  <option value="cart.php?a=add&pid=1548&billingcycle=triennially">
  <h3>SAVE 70%</h3>
    <span class="hp-disc-price">3 Year at <strike>$432.00/mo</strike></span>
    <span class="hp-price">$129.60/mo</span>
  </option>
</select>
</div>

    <p class="hecont act">Attractive selling introduction to the plan followed by an unordered list. <strong>Save huge</strong>
with a pro-plan!</p>

<ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Disk Storage Space</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Accounts</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Antivirus Filtering</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Anti-spam Filtering</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Auto Responders</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> IMAP / POP3 Protocols</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Control Panel</li>
</ul>

<a class="but_small1" href="#features">View Features</a> <a id="order-btn"> Order now </a>
</div>

    document.getElementById("dynamic_select").onclick = function() {
    
    document.getElementById("order-btn").href = "https://example.com/"+this.value+"/";
    
}

.ive-hpbox{
  width:350px;
  border:1px solid #a1a1a1;
  border-radius:.25em;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
}
.ive-hpbox:hover{
  box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}

#dynamic_select option .hp-saving {
  font-size:26px;
}

#dynamic_select {
  border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
  background:#fff;
  width:90%;
}

.ive-hpbox ul{
  display:block;
  text-align:left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6rsgnmdy/52/

Comment: You should consider using a UI framework like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com). Check out its [dropdown component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/). If nothing else, you can copy the markup and styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done using a select/option tag.

I have seen people doing this with a `<input type=radio>` combined with a `label`. Hide the radio button, and each option is being written out in the label. Though then you still need to add JavaScript to show the selected value and the open/close to show all the options.

Other people also might do this with div's, but I personally don't like it, as with the radio/label solution you are still controlling the form directly instead of using JavaScript and you only use JS for visibility.